# Set specific routing parameter retrievable by ActivatedRoute

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

When defining a router in my application, I had to write a query parameter that was then interpreted in my application by calling the ActivatedRoute (the parameter MUST be retrievable for compatibility issues). Lately, I had to define some new sub-routes that doesn't follow the same routing logic.

```
// Works but no param sent when myParam is selected
{
  path: "myParam",
  component: "MyComponent"
}, {
  path: ":param",
  children: [{/* */}]
}
//...

// doesn't work when first guard isn't ok
{
path: ":param",
  component: "MyFirstComponent",
  canActivate: [myGuardService]
}, {
path: ":param",
  canActivate: [myOtherGuardService]
  children: [{/* */}]
}
//...
```

First, I tried to define specific routes before the generic one but the parameter was not sent..
Then, I tried to set a guard on each one on the same level but when the first guard doesn't apply on the input, the route wasn't accessible anymore.
That seems simple but I'm unable to find a way to fix it with minimum code change
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I redirected the new component the new path which I declared at the same level as the two others. This way, the parameters were always retrievable.